# "laravel.log could not be opened" error on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, logging

I've deployed a Laravel application on AWS ElasticBeanstalk (PHP 7.3 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.9.7).
The application runs fine when it does, but randomly throws following error for few requests.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or
>   file "/var/app/current/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened:
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /var/app/current/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:110\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/app/current/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(42):
>   Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array)\n#1
>   /var/app/current/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(323):
>   Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)\n#2
>   /var/app/current/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(541):
>   Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, 'Unhandled Excep...', Array)\n#3
>   /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Logger.php(174):
>   Monolog\Logger->error('Unhandled Excep...', Array)\n#4
>   /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Logger.php(87):
>   Illuminate\Log\Logger->writeLog('error', 'Unhandled Excep...',
>   Array)\n#5
>   /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(54
>   in
>   /var/app/current/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php
>   on line 110

I dont understand why it throws error for some requests only and not others. Nonetheless i tried applying the permissions to the storage and bootstrap folders as suggested by few posts through .ebextensions as below but did not get it working.

```
"/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_make_storage_writable.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      echo "Making /storage and /bootstrap writeable..."
      chmod -R 777 /var/app/current/storage
      chmod -R 777 /var/app/current/bootstrap
```

Can someone please help me here? I'm new to Laravel and AWS both and very confused as to what might be wrong here.

Comment: Is your app running as root? Did you try just deleting the log file and seeing if it will create a new one on its own?

Comment: @ahackney the app is running as ec2-user (used "ps aux | grep apache" to get the user). Deleted the file and it created a new one on it's own.

Comment: I've enabled the logs to be collected in tail logs and bundle logs, would that create any problem (suspecting as this is happening sporadically)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your setting the owner to root:root and the apache user is ec2-user.

When you delete the existing log, the correct user will create the new log and it'll work as needed. You could also chown the files to the ec2-user and that would work too.

Comment: Wont this script just change the permissions? i think the owner and group are for the shell script file that it is generating. Am i missing something here?

Though i added sudo to the commands and am not seeing the error anymore. Although these errors appears back randomly, will keep the thread up to date for everyone curious.